# Expand and collapse JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, list

I heed help for to add expand and collapse to my following JavaScript code.I want +(plus) image when collapse and -(minus) image when expand. Please help me with code to do that.Please see the dataSource, , if i click on watch it will expand and watch will be displayed, and when i again click on watch titan will disappear.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aliparvez20/Ek2xS/8/)

```
var dataSource = ({
            "Watch": ({
                "Titan": ({}),
            })
        }),
    traverseObject = function (obj) {
        var ul = document.createElement("ul"),
            li;

        for (var prop in obj) {
            li = document.createElement("li");
            li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(prop));
            li.onclick = function(){alert("Hello")}

            if (typeof obj[prop] == "object" && Object.keys(obj[prop]).length) {
                li.appendChild(traverseObject(obj[prop]));

            }
            ul.appendChild(li);
            console.log(ul);
        }
        return ul;
    };


window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById("dvList1").appendChild(traverseObject(dataSource));
}
```

Comment: can u provide a fiddle for this?

Comment: Remove every `(` and `)` from this at the beginning: `var dataSource = ({ "Watch": ({ "Titan": ({}),  })  })`

Comment: @user3237973 check my updated answer, that should work for IE as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Live jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ek2xS/20/)

I have removed the unnecessary parenthesis from your dataSource and added a third level for testing purposes.

Besides that, what I changed was your `onclick` to

```
li.onclick = function(e) {
                e.currentTarget.classList.toggle("hidden");
                e.stopPropagation();
            }
```

and placed an `else` statement that adds a class `leaf` for leaf nodes (we don't want to see minus and plus signs on those nodes).

```
if (typeof obj[prop] == "object" && Object.keys(obj[prop]).length) {
    li.appendChild(traverseObject(obj[prop]));
} else {
    li.classList.add("leaf");
}
```

and also added some CSS that displays the signs in pseudo elements:

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
}

li.hidden ul {
    display: none;
}

li:before {
    content: '-';
    width: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}

li.hidden:before {
    content: '+';
}

li.leaf:before {
    content: '';
}

li {
    cursor: pointer;
}

li.leaf {
    cursor: default;
}
```

---

**EDIT:**

IE does not support `classList`, so replaced it by `className`. This [**solution**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ek2xS/24/) should work for all browsers.

Comment: I imagine you are getting this dataSource as a result of a back-end request? If so, then you should sort there on the server. But if you need to sort on the browser, you can use [Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) to sort a dataSource based on arrays of json objects

Comment: Sir i am still stuck with the sorting part can you please provide me a jfiddle